# Why am I getting a type mismatch error in this code?

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication

[The Firebase `UserCredential` interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredential_interface) has a field called `user` that is of type `User`. I have a method that accepts a parameter of type `User`, but when I call the method, I get the following error:

> The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'.

I am fetching my `UserCredential` by awaiting [`signInAnonymously()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signinanonymously) which returns a `Promise<UserCredential>`, so I'm not sure how `userCredential.user` is being typed as `User?`.

Here is my code:

```
loginAno() async {
    UserCredential userCredential =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
    onSignInAno(userCredential.user); // Problem Is Here 
}
```

Why am I getting this error? `userCredential.user` is a `User`, not a `User?`.

Comment: userCredential.user creating problem

Answer (score 1):

The `userCredential.user` field may be `null`, so it is declared as `User?`.

Since your `onSignInAno` expects a `User`, you should only call it when `userCredential.user` is not null. So:

```
loginAno() async {
    UserCredential userCredential =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
    if (userCredential.user !== null) {
        onSignInAno(userCredential.user);
    }
}
```